# control flow graph generator for c# code

Tags: c#, graph, generator, control-flow

i need a tool that takes c# code and generate the control flow graph of the code
if there's something like this in visual studio ............ do please point it out to me
thanks

Answer (score 2):

right-click, Generate Sequence Diagram

Comment: i'm sorry but this is not the answer i' looking for what i need is a tool to generate control flow graphs (CFG) which is used in software testing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph